# System.TypeLoadException was unhandled: Could not load type because the method has no implementation (no RVA)

Tags: c#, reflection

i am trying to execute commands by entering a string. I have the following class:

```
abstract class ECommand {
    public static bool TryExecute(string raw, out object result) {
        string name = raw; //function trigger
        if (!Config.CommandRegister.ContainsKey(name)) {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        Type datType = Config.CommandRegister[name];
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(datType);
        MethodInfo method = datType.GetMethod("Execute");
        result = method.Invoke(instance, null);

        return true;
    }

    public extern object Execute();
}
```

Strings and equivalent types are registered in a Dictionary like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> CommandRegister = 
new Dictionary<string, Type> { {"test", typeof(TestECommand)} };
```

I try to test it on this class:

```
class TestECommand : ECommand {
    public new object Execute() {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        return "k";
    }
}
```

When calling it

```
ECommand.TryExecute(source, out res);
```

i get the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233054
  Message=Could not load type 'Test.ECommand' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'Execute' has no implementation (no RVA).
  Source=Test
  TypeName=Test.ECommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that your assembly containing TestECommand is old and compiled against ECommand when ECommand had an implementation for Execute(). I'm also guessing that you've changed ECommand.Execute to abstract, removing the implementation, without recompiling the assembly hosting TestECommand. A recompilation (and cleanup of old resources) will solve the problem, if my guesses are correct. (Also make sure that you dont have old file references that aren't updated on recompilations.)

Comment: I did not alter the code. And everything is in one project, so I dont see the point where something could be out of date? At my further research I also found answers like this, but they seem to have used libraries which were not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing `extern` keyword - its generally used for P/invoke.

I think you meant `abstract`

```
public abstract object Execute();
```